# Move images to folders based on img.shape value

Tags: python, dictionary

I've made a program which take a folder of images and, for each one, find the width through `img.shape` function.
Then, it create a dict which contains the following values: `[(filename, width)]`.

How can, at this point, move the files (based on a shape value I give) to specified folders?
I mean, if I give as condition a value of 50 pixels, how can I tell the program to move each corresponding image to a folder?

```
import os
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import statistics
from heapq import nsmallest

src = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\roiseparator\\roi_single\\')

imgs = os.listdir(src)
sorted_imgs = imgs.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))

lista_roi = []
lista_w = []

lista_key_value = {}

for i, roi in enumerate(imgs):

    image = cv2.imread(str(src) + str(imgs[i]))

    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    lista_roi.append(i)  
    lista_w.append(w)  

for i in range(len(lista_roi)):
    lista_key_value[lista_roi[i]] = lista_w[i] 

lista_key_value = list(lista_key_value.items()) 

print('Key - Value: ', lista_key_value)
```

Result of print is: `[(0, 37), (1, 30), (2, 34), (3, 30), (4, 31), (5, 31), (6, 37), (7, 37), (8, 60), (9, 73), (10, 53)]`

It have to be read as: `(filename,width)`.

Example of output: if width =< 50, move all files which satisfy this condition to a folder. Warn: `50` is not a stable value, it is most a variable and it's recognized in the second half of the code.

I find difficult, at this point, to recover the file (image) using the value of width.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
import os
from os.path import join
import cv2

src = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\roiseparator\\roi_single\\')
dest = #destination dir
width_threshold = 50

imgs = os.listdir(src)
sorted_imgs = imgs.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
imgs_widths = []

for img_name in sorted_imgs:

    image = cv2.imread(str(src) + img_name)

    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    imgs_widths.append(w)

# printing stuff
for img_name, img_width in zip(sorted_imgs, imgs_widths):
    print("Image: ", img_name, "has width: ", img_width)

# set width here after watching the printed stuff
width_threshold = int(input())

# filter images based on width
for img_name, img_width in zip(sorted_imgs, imgs_widths):
    if img_width > width_threshold:
        old_file = join(src, img_name)
        new_file = join(dest, img_name)
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Comment: Ok, let's say that the value (50 in your case) is not a stable number but a variable I found after last print. So I cant put the condition at the first for loop. It don't work..

Comment: edited my answer as per the requirement you mentioned in your comment

Comment: is it giving an error or your objective is not achieved ?

Comment: I made some changes in the call to `rename` function from `os` module, hope this helps. If my answer helped you, then feel free to upvote it or select it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on tkhurana96 answer, I made it work using `shutil` module:

```
import shutil    

dest = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\roiseparator\\folder\\')

for imgs, img_width in zip(imgs, lista_w):
    print("Image: ", imgs, "has width: ", img_width)

    if img_width <= magic_number:  # magic number is a variable number
        shutil.move(str(src) + imgs, dest)
```